# Why does my original array get spliced if I splice the cloned array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, behavior

I have the following code:

```
 var coords = [
     {lat: 39.57904, lng: -8.98094, type: "a"}, // A
     {lat: 39.55436, lng: -8.95493, type: "b"}, // B
     {lat: 39.56634, lng: -8.95836, type: "c"} // C
 ];

 var travelingOptions = [];

 getAllTravelingOptions();

 function getAllTravelingOptions(){
     coords.forEach((point, pos) => {
         let c = coords;
         delete c[pos];
         console.log(c);
         console.log(coords);
     });
 }
```

Why is it that variable `c` and `coords` are always the same? If I delete on `c`, it mirrors the action on `coords`. Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: `c` and `coords` are both references to the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the assignment of `c`, you get the reference of the array `coords`.

Any change of `coords` does effect `c`, until a new value is assigned to `c`.

If you make a copy of the array with `Array.slice`, you get a new array but with the same reference of the objects. When changing one object inside, you are changing the same object with the same reference in `c`.

```js
var coords = [
         {lat: 39.57904, lng: -8.98094, type: "a"}, // A
         {lat: 39.55436, lng: -8.95493, type: "b"}, // B
         {lat: 39.56634, lng: -8.95836, type: "c"} // C
     ],
     c = coords.slice();

console.log(c);
coords[1].type = 'foo';
console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assignment does not clone array it only creates reference to the orginal object/array. You can use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to make a shallow copy:

```
let c = coords.slice();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `c` and `coords` now reference the same object. To prevent this, use `let c = coords.slice()` to create a copy of `coords` and assign it to `c`.

```js
let original = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let test = original;
let testSlice = original.slice();

original[0] = 12345;

console.log('test: ', test)
console.log('testSlice: ', testSlice)
```

However, the new array will still reference the same objects that the old array did. A quick fix for this would be 'cloning' these objects.

```js
let objs = [
  {'obj': 1},
  {'obj': 2},
  {'obj': 3}
];

let newArr = [];

objs.forEach(obj => {
 let newObj = {};
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
   newObj[key] = obj[key];
  });
  newArr.push(newObj);
});

console.log('old: ', objs)
console.log('new: ', newArr)

newArr[0].obj = 12345;

console.log('old after changing obj on new: ', objs)
```